# Passing data between intern test suites

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, intern

I have a very large test suite edit_person_test.js that I am trying to decompose into smaller test suites. I would like to call smaller suites like add_person_cancel.js from a main suite and pass data created in the main suite's before() into the smaller test suites (edit_person_test.js line 75). However when I try and access the data in the smaller test suite it is still null. How can I create one copy of the data and pass it into every smaller test suite?

```
// Very large parent suite add_person_test.js
define([
  'intern!object',
  'pages/PersonTabPage',
  'pages/AddPersonPage',
  'data-objects/PersonData',
  './add_person_cancel'
], function(registerSuite, PersonTabPage, AddPersonPage, Person, addPersonCancel) {

registerSuite(function() {

  var personTabPage = null;
  var addPersonPage = null;
  var person = null;

  return {
    // Assumes we are logged in
    name: 'Edit Person Test',

    before: function() {
      person = new Person(); // randomly generated data to create person with
      personTabPage = new PersonTabPage(this.remote, this.timeout);
      addPersonPage = new AddPersonPage(this.remote, this.timeout);
    },

    // calling smaller suite here
    AddPersonCancel: addPersonCancel.CancelAddPersonTest(personTabPage, addPersonPage, person),

  };
});
});
```

---

```
// Smaller test suite add_person_cancel.js
define(function() {

  return function(personTabPage, addPersonPage, person) {
    return {
      // Assumes we are logged in
      name: 'Cancel Add Person Test',

      OpenAddPersonPage: function() {
        logger.info(person);
        return personTabPage.clickAddPerson()
          .getAccumulatedState();
      },

      ValidateButtonDisabledStatus: function() {
        return addPersonPage.personButtonStatus(function(status) {
            assert.isFalse(status, 'Buttons are enabled even before entering person name');
          })
          .getAccumulatedState();
      },

      EnterNameClickCancelButton: function() {
        return addPersonPage.enterFirstName(person.firstName)
          .enterLastName(person.lastName)
          .clickCancelButton()
          .waitForPageReady()
          .getAccumulatedState();
      },

      CheckPersonNameNotSaved: function() {
        return personTabPage
          .findInPersonsTableAssertion(person.firstName + ' ' + person.lastName, false, function(result) {
            assert.isFalse(result, 'Person name is saved even on closing the trowser using Cancel button');
          })
          .getAccumulatedState();
      }
    };
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This CancelAddPersonTest function is wrong:

```
 AddPersonCancel: addPersonCancel.CancelAddPersonTest(personTabPage, addPersonPage, person),
```

This call occurs as the object literal is being constructed, at which point nothing has ever run (you’re still creating the object literal that will define the test structure) so all those variables you’re passing are all null, and always will be.

The simplest solution is to create an object early and then pass it to `CancelAddPersonTest` instead of individual variables:

```
var personState = {
  personTabPage: null,
  addPersonPage: null,
  person: null
};

return {
  // ...

  before: function() {
    personState.person = new Person(); // randomly generated data to create person with
    personState.personTabPage = new PersonTabPage(this.remote, this.timeout);
    personState.addPersonPage = new AddPersonPage(this.remote, this.timeout);
  },

  // ...

  AddPersonCancel: addPersonCancel.CancelAddPersonTest(personState)
};
```

Now, use the properties of that object in `CancelAddPersonTest` as you are trying to use the parameters now, and things will work as you want them to.